# Goodness-of-fit for Lomax distribution

Tags: goodness-of-fit

I have some data n > 3000 https://drive.google.com/file/d/1gwB_U_TOX-IQHZJJDX-WeErLzrZZFoXu/view?usp=sharing (Third column) that I believe based on my physical theory should follow a Lomax distribution.
$$
f(x) = \frac{ks^k}{(k + x)^{s+1}} ~~~~~x>0
$$
The parameters of the model are determined by theory and are
$$
s, k = 7.82\times 10^{-6}, 2.21
$$

The goal is to twofold.
First, I need to determine whether this is a good model for the data particularly near the right tail. Second, I need to compare this model with an exponential fit to the data. To that end, I first used `expparetotest` from `LREP` package which test whether data comes from a Pareto distribution and the results confirm that the distribution of data is Pareto and not exponential. I also use the "Jackson" test from the package `Renext` which gives me the following results.

```
$statistic
[1] 3.326906

$df
[1] 3185

$p.value
[1] 0
```

I then use `pareto2_test_ad` from `agop` to test if the data is Pareto II, which I have read is the same as Lomax. However, I am getting the following results.

```
pareto2_test_ad(my_data, 7.8e-6)
W = 467.93, p-value < 2.2e-16
```

Which if I understand correctly means data is not coming from the specified distribution.

Additionally, I am using `result = gpdAd(lowFreq, bootstrap = TRUE, bootnum = 300)` from `eva`
and I get

```
$statistic
[1] 17.55134

$p.value
[1] 0.003311258

$theta
       Scale        Shape 
7.517058e-07 1.478888e+00
```

My questions:

1. Is my approach correct? Is AD test a good test to determine whether my data comes from Lomax distribution.
2. Why do the estimates of the parameters are different from mine?
3. Why does p-value change with `bootnum`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could fit the distribution using the `gamlss` package in `R` and inspect diagnostic plots. To check whether the fitted parameters are consistent with the theoretical parameters, you could use Wald tests or confidence intervals for the parameters (see below).

Let's fit the distribution and check the diagnostics (I assume the data is loaded and named `dat`):

```
library(gamlss)
library(gamlss.dist)
# Fit Lomax distribution
mod <- gamlss(X0~1, family = PARETO2o, data = dat)

plot(mod) # Diagnostic plots
wp(mod, ylim.all = c(1)) # Worm-plot (detrended Q-Q plot)
dtop(mod) # Detrended Owen's plot
```

[image: Diagnostics]

Here are the worm plot (upper panel) and Owen's plot (lower panel):

[image: WP]

The Q-Q plot and the worm plot as well as Owen's plot show that the Lomax is not a good fit for the data, especially the right tail.

The fitted parameters can be retrieved by:

```
exp(coef(mod, "mu"))
exp(coef(mod, "sigma"))
```

So $\hat{\sigma} = 0.6768762$ (this is $k$ in your formula) and $\hat{\mu}= 5.09676\times 10^{-7}$ ($s$ in your formula). To check whether these are consistent with $\sigma = 2.21$ and $\mu = 7.82\times 10^{-6}$, let's do a joint Wald test for both coefficients:

```
Vmat <- vcov(mod) # Covariance matrix
coefmat <- matrix(c(coef(mod, "mu"), coef(mod, "sigma")), 2, 1) # Coefficient matrix
Lmat <- matrix(c(1, 0, 0, 1), 2, 2) # Hypothesis matrix
cmat <- matrix(c(log(2.21), log(7.82e-6)), 2, 1) # Hypothesized values
# Wald-statistic
Fval <- (1/2)*(t((Lmat%*%coefmat - cmat))%*%solve(Lmat%*%Vmat%*%t(Lmat))%*%(Lmat%*%coefmat - cmat))
# P-value
1 - pf(Fval, 2, df.residual(mod))
[1] 0
```

The $p$-value is practically $0$ indicating that the model is not consistent with the theoretical values.

Finally, let's calculate the confidence intervals for the parameters:

```
exp(confint(mod))
                         2.5 %       97.5 %
mu.(Intercept)    4.483221e-07 5.794263e-07
sigma.(Intercept) 6.359687e-01 7.204151e-01
```

The $95\,\%$ confidence interval for $\mu$ is $(4.48\times 10^{-7};5.79\times 10^{-7})$ and for $\sigma$ it's $(0.636; 0.720)$. The theoretical values are not part of the intervals, reaffirming our conclusion that the fitted model is not compatible with the theoretical paramter values.

Answer (score 1):

You could use a Kolmogorov-Smirnov (KS) test by plugging
Maximum-Likelihood estimates into the target (Lomax) distribution
function. Although the KS test should use a fully specified
distribution (with no estimated parameters) using estimated parameters
works fine when the number of observations is large as is the case
here.

Inasmuch the interest seems to be on the tail, one can use the Peaks
Over Threshold (POT) approach, which consists in fitting a
distribution for the excesses over a threshold $u$ chosen to high
enough. So instead of the original observations $Y_i$ we use the
*excesses* $Y_i -u$, selecting the observations with $Y_i > u$. In
this approach we favour the Generalized Pareto Distribution (GPD) for
the excesses, because this distribution is "POT"-stable. The Lomax
is a special case of the GPD.

Note that the data are poorly scaled which may lead to problems with
estimation routines. This may explain why your estimates (which I
suspect are given in the wrong order) differ from those coming from
different packages. I would recommend to scale the data. It is also
worth noting that if a specific order exists for the observations
(e.g. records in time) these could have different "regimes". If the
whole distribution was to be investigated, we would probably have to
use a mixture of parametric distributions as suggested by the density
of logged observations obtained with `density`.

```
> dat <- 1e5 * dat[ , 3]
> library(Renext)
> fitL <- flomax(dat)
> coL <- fitL$estimate
> coL

##      shape      scale 
## 0.67633153 0.05085796

> ks.test(x = dat, y = "plomax", scale = coL["scale"], shape = coL["shape"])

## Warning in ks.test.default(x = dat, y = "plomax", scale = coL["scale"], : ties
## should not be present for the Kolmogorov-Smirnov test

## 
##  Asymptotic one-sample Kolmogorov-Smirnov test
## 
## data:  dat
## D = 0.055853, p-value = 4.688e-09
## alternative hypothesis: two-sided
```

So we clearly reject the null hypothesis: the observations can not be regarded as forming a sample of a Lomax distribution.

Now let us try a POT model.

```
> u <- 3.0
> exc <- dat[dat > u] - u
> fitL2 <- flomax(exc)
> coL2 <- fitL2$estimate
> ks.test(x = exc, y = "plomax", scale = coL2["scale"], shape = coL2["shape"])

## Warning in ks.test.default(x = exc, y = "plomax", scale = coL2["scale"], : ties
## should not be present for the Kolmogorov-Smirnov test

## 
##  Asymptotic one-sample Kolmogorov-Smirnov test
## 
## data:  exc
## D = 0.047207, p-value = 0.9009
## alternative hypothesis: two-sided
```

The Kolmogorov-Smirnov test tells that a Lomax distribution is quite good for the chosen threshold. The same conclusion seems to arise with different choices of the threshold.

Now let us turn to the question: could the tail be exponential rather
than Lomax?  This is nearly a routine test in POT and we can use
`LRExp.test`, the null hypothesis being an exponential distribution. As
explained in the documentation, the Likelihood-Ratio test uses by
default a numeric approximation of the test statistic. We can use a simulation method to get a more
precise result as follows

```
LRExp.test(exc, method = "sim", nSamp = 100000)
   ## $statistic
   ## [1] 5.662787
   ## 
   ## $df
   ## [1] 146
   ## 
   ## $p.value
   ## [1] 0.00541
   ## 
   ## $method
   ## [1] "LR test of exponentiality"
   ## 
   ## $alternative
   ## [1] "lomax"
```

So clearly we should reject the exponentiality (of the tail) and favour
the Lomax alternative. Though slightly less powerful, we could have used Jackson's test similarly (with the same conclusion).

We could have use the `Renouv` function of *Renext* to fit
a POT model. The KS test would then on "jitterized" version of the observations to remove ties hence discard the warning.